# Make video from image sequences each image sequence and video in different folder

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, video, video-processing

I have CASIA gait database. The database contains 2 Datasets. Each dataset has different folders for subjects eg. 001, 001 etc. Each subject has different walking condition eg. with a bag (bg), with a coat (cl) etc.. Again, these conditions are divided into various angles eg. 000, 018, 054,090 etc. So the path looks something like this "D:\GAIT\DATABASE\GaitDatasetB-silh\DatasetB\silhouettes\001\001\bg-01\054" 
In these folders, there are image sequences named as 001-bg-01-054-007.png

So you can imagine there are thousands of folders. I want to make a video out of each image sequence and store the video in the same folder as the image sequence. I can do it one by on in Matlab and Java.

I am searching for a program which can do it **all at once**. The program should be able to recognize all folders and make videos out of each sequence all by itself. Since the no. of frames and angle are random I can't get it done via a program.

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be easily done with Matlab using the ["dir" function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to browse through your folders and subfolders. Then you will have to loop through every image in each subfolder and make a movie. You don't need to know the number of images of each subfolder since you will loop through all of them.  I'll write you a pseudocode, rest is homework:

1. `pdir = uigetdir(pwd, ['Choose the parent directory where you have all subfolders']);`
2. `list_subfolders_level_1 = dir(pdir); % be carefur since "dir" lists folders AND files`
3. If necessary repeat 2 for more subfolder levels (looping like `dir(list_subfolders_level_1(idx))` where `idx = 1:length(list_subfolders_level_1)`)
4. Once you are at the image-level you can make the movie:

   - `list_images = dir(name_of_image_level_dir)`
   - `cd(name_of_image_level_dir)`
   - loop through your images while building a movie for that specific subfolder. For that just check [this matlab procedure](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/convert-between-image-sequences-and-video.html).